# Will the size of the pinhole affect the size of the image produced?

Tags: optics

If we have a larger pinhole, would it produce a larger image? 
I know the size of the opening will affect the brightness and sharpness of the image, but what about its size? If you think about it, a wider opening will make the light rays more spread out and therefore consequently produce a bigger (and also blurrier) image on the screen. I guess I'm just really confused.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A larger pinhole in a pinhole camera does not make the image larger ; it simply makes each "point" in the image blurrier.  A way to think about it is to consider the image to be the superposition of a large number of essentually identical images, each produced by a different sub-pinhole in the large pinhole.  The result is that each image "point" is blurred by an amount equal to the size of the large pinhole.